# React.js: Passing props using JS Destructring

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

In react.js, are there any differences between the following two approaches? like in terms of performance etc?

1. `<SomeComponent props1={props1} props2={props2} />`
2. `<SomeComponent { ...{props1, props2} } />`

Comment: They do the same thing. I prefer the second approach because it's less repetitive and reduces the chance of typos.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I personally guess that 2nd approach might be worse in terms of performance, because it will generate a new object everytime it renders, so it might cause additional re-rendering? but I am not quite sure

Comment: It could be slightly worse, but it would be absolutely insignificant. Not something to worry about. No, it won't cause extra re-rendering.

Answer (score 4):

use babel, see result:

```
const component1 = <SomeComponent props1={props1} props2={props2} />
const component2 = <SomeComponent { ...{props1, props2} } />
```

```js
"use strict";

const component1 = /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(SomeComponent, {
  props1: props1,
  props2: props2
});
const component2 = /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(SomeComponent, {
  props1,
  props2
});
```

Comment: Excellent analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Those two approaches are exactly same in performance. Because spread operator doesn't affect to the performance. I think the second one is the good use case than the first one.